# Am I overreacting to company taking time to email documents?

Tags: professionalism, hiring-process, job-offer, email

Last week I received an email stating that I will be receiving a formal offer during the course of this week and then two business days later I received a phone call asking for my formal answer to which I said yes, and the person said that they will try to email the next business day or two. It has been about three business days now and still no word. Mind you this is a big multinational company and I received a start date and salary which is a while from now since it's just a summer position.

I feel very anxious although they have even congratulated me on this job so perhaps I am just over-thinking it. Would it be appropriate to send an email to the HR person who called me and asked me for the job to check up on how are the documents coming along or should I just wait until the end of this week?

Comment: Im going to second PaulDonny's answer.  I was in the same situation about a year ago.  I got offered an internship and accepted it and didn't hear anything back for almost 2 months and then a couple weeks before my start date it all came together.  Be patient even though its hard and congratulations!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### You have the job, quit worrying

Yes, it can take a while especially for a multinational company to get the ball moving. You can contact the HR rep if you like but since there is plenty of time until your start date not too many people are likely worried about this so why should you?

Congratulations on the job, stop stressing and enjoy the moment.